# Need some feedback with PHP+C polyglot code and class/struct properties

Tags: tips, polyglot, c, php

If you consider the following PHP+C polyglot snippet, there is a problem regarding class property access in the printf call:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define class struct
#define function 

class Point {
#define public int
    public $x;
    public $y;
};

int
function main()
{
    struct Point*
    $p = alloca(sizeof(struct Point));
    printf("%d", $p->x);  // PHP expects $p->x, but C expects $p->$x
    return 0;
}
```

My question is, how to resolve this in a neat manner? Possible solutions:

1. Remove all `$` via sed before compiling with gcc
2. Define `public $x` as `int x` using `#if __PHP__`
3. Edit: Use getters, maybe? (works in C by passing self as first argument with function pointers)

Trying to define dollar sign as empty space does not work:

```
#define $
```

Any other ideas? I am also considering using m4 in the C Makefile. Thank you. :)

Comment: @py3programmer Already asked in the chat.

Comment: Would this be possible `#define $b int` then `$b= $x="x"` maybe? I have not tried it

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Glad to see a non-[tag:code-golf] [tag:tips] question, there's very few of them.

Comment: @py3programmer https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte

Comment: @RadvylfPrograms I'm not sure this one is allowed though, as it lacks an objective winning criterion to work towards (other than "make it work")

Comment: Can you throw in a `#define x $x`, then use `$p->x`?

Comment: @user Heck yes, that works! Thanks! Feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: Currently, I think this is borderline off-topic. While [polyglot]s are a part of this site, the main thing every question here needs to have is a winning criteria: what part of this polyglot are you attempting to optimise? Without that, this is more on-topic on SO than here

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Feel free to follow discussion in chat. No way this would be allowed in SO, but maybe on a subreddit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `#define x $x` with the other `#define`s at the top. Now `$p->x` should also work in C.

Comment: Btw, this also works for properties with similar names, like $x and $xx, without causing collisions.

Comment: OK, so there's one problem - if someone defines a function called `x` at the same time... :d Have to think about that one.

Comment: Simple solution: Just namespace the variables with `__object_prop_x` or sim to avoid collision.